# Is it possible to customize IntelliJ IDEA 14.0's "Refresh all Gradle projects" / Gradle projects sync behavior?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

When I hit the [Refresh all Gradle projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html) button in IntelliJ IDEA, it uses its built-in Gradle scripts comprehension mechanism to produce the IDE's build configuration. However, it doesn't always do exactly what I want. Is there a way to customize its behavior? Perhaps make IDEA understand Gradle's [IDEA plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html)?

Experiments show that IntelliJ IDEA is completely oblivious to the `apply plugin: 'idea'`. There is no auto-complete and no Gradle tasks from it are recognized. The [IDEA's Gradle integration roadmap](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Gradle+integration) linked from Gradle's [tooling page](http://www.gradle.org/tooling) is severely outdated and doesn't seem to mention anything on this subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ *is* affected by `apply plugin: 'idea'` (which should always be done) and (some of the) related configuration in the build script. There is already quite some auto-completion, but obviously it's not perfect yet. Expect improvements with every new IntelliJ and Gradle release.

For now, if you want utmost customizability, consider generating the IntelliJ project with `gradle idea`, rather than using IntelliJ's Gradle integration.

Comment: Two places where the `apply plugin: 'idea'` seems to have no effect on IntelliJ:

1) no new task is added in IntelliJ's "Gradle tasks" from the `idea` plugin.  

2) I created a Gradle-based project with IntelliJ. I added `withXml` example from IdeaModule Gradle DSL doc to Gradle script. IntelliJ's "gradle refresh" didn't picked it up (the `.iml` file was not modified). It worked with Gradle from cmd line (`gradlew.bat ideaModule`).  

I guess the way to go is to just follow your suggestion of using the `idea` Gradle plugin.

Comment: `withXml` doesn't affect IntelliJ's Gradle support because it isn't integrating at the XML level but using the Gradle tooling API. You should definitely see some new tasks once you are applying the `idea` plugin. (However, these tasks are irrelevant when using IntelliJ's Gradle support, so maybe they are filtered out.)